# Using VBA to Loop Through Sheets with a Specific Name

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I am trying to build a macro to run through a file and open a userform for every sheet that has the name "File-n" where n is an integer. I've tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim indx As Integer

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    WS.Activate

    If WS.Name = "File-" & indx Then
        WS.Select
        userform1.show
    End If

Next WS
```

This macro doesn't recognize any sheets. The code below works, but I was hoping to clean it up if possible. I don't like listing out the potential number of sheets up to thirty.

```
If WS.Name = "File-0" or WS.Name = "File-1" or WS.Name = "File-2" or ... Then
```

Comment: Possibly an easier approach - do you have any sheets with names starting with `"File-"` that you *don't* want to consider?

Comment: @BigBen No, all sheets with the name "File-" would be relevant in this case.

Comment: Then just use `InStr` (see the posted answer), or `Left` even.

Comment: Try to avoid `.Activate` and `.Select` if not expressly needed for user communication - c.f. [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?r=SearchResults&s=1|191.2192)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Like` as @BigBen mentioned in comment or use `Instr` like below:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim indx As Integer

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    WS.Activate

    If InStr(1, LCase(WS.Name), "file") Then
        WS.Select
        UserForm1.Show
    End If

Next WS

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

See if below code helps

```
Dim WS As Worksheet

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    WS.Activate
    If WS.Name Like "File-*" Then
        WS.Select
        userform1.show
    End If
Next WS
```

Comment: This would compare each Worksheet against an incremental indx number, so I doubt it would work as expected...

Comment: @Xabier thank you for pointing this out. I see where the mistake is! I have corrected the code.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more loop for indx

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim indx As Integer
For i = 1 to 30
    indx  = i
For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    WS.Activate
    If WS.Name = "File-" & i Then
       userform1.show
    End If
Next WS
Next i
```

Comment: If you were to do this approach, the outer loop should be the worksheet loop, and the inner loop should be `i`. But... it's really inefficient and there are way better approaches.